# How to print message from a server to the textclient?

Tags: java

I want to print message from a server.For example:I am User1 and I am chatting with user User2.
I want to see this(in the text client console):
  User1:Hello
  User2:Hi!How are you?

I can see  the messages I sent but only in the Server console.Here is my code(to show message in console in text client class):
EDIT:I have put all the classes that I modified.I didn't put the exceptions classes,ServerConfig and Message and PrivateMessage.ServerConfig return port 9000 and max clients 100,the method getAll() from message returns the message+sender.

```
     import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

  public class ClientPeer extends Thread{

  String _username;
   Socket _Socket;

   public ClientPeer(String _username, Socket _Socket)

  {
    this._username = _username;
    this._Socket = _Socket;
  }
public void run()

  {
try{    
    ObjectInputStream _objin=new ObjectInputStream(_Socket.getInputStream());
    Message _messfromserver=(Message)_objin.readObject();
    System.out.println(_messfromserver.getAll());

}catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
 catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

public void sendMessage(String _message) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream _obj = new ObjectOutputStream(
            _Socket.getOutputStream());
    _obj.writeObject(new Message(_username, _message));
    _obj.flush();

}

public void sendMessage(String _message, String _receiver)
        throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream _obj = new ObjectOutputStream(
            _Socket.getOutputStream());
    _obj.writeObject(new PrivateMessage(_username, _message, _receiver));
    _obj.flush();
}
     }
```

Server :

```
         import java.io.*;
      import java.net.*;
           import java.util.*;

             public class Server {
         static ServerConfig _svconfig = new ServerConfig();

// final static int _mysocket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
        final int _mysocket = _svconfig.getPORTNumber();
        ServerSocket _serversocket = new ServerSocket(_mysocket);
        Socket _clientsocket = _serversocket.accept();
        ServerPeer _serverpeer = new ServerPeer(_clientsocket);
        _serverpeer.methodCall();
        _serversocket.close();
    }


    catch (MissingKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BindException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("You have been disconnected");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

TextClient:

```
               import java.io.*;
     import java.net.*;
      import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    public class TextClient {
        public TextClient() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        UnknownHostException, ConnectException,InterruptedException {

    Socket _socket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
    System.out.println("Please enter your desired username:");
    Scanner _new = new Scanner(System.in);
    String _inputname = _new.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Success.You can now type your messages!");
    ClientPeer _clientpeer = new ClientPeer(_inputname, _socket);
    Scanner _scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String _input = _scan.nextLine();
   _clientpeer.start();
    while (true) {


        if (!_input.equals("exit")) {
            if (_input.startsWith("/w"))
                _clientpeer.sendMessage(_input, "username");
            else
                _clientpeer.sendMessage(_input);

        } else
            break;

        _input = _scan.nextLine();
    }
       }
   }
```

ServerPeer:

```
      import java.net.*;
     import java.io.*;

   public class ServerPeer {
     Socket _socket;

public ServerPeer(Socket _socket) {
    this._socket = _socket;
 }

public void methodCall() throws IOException, UnknownHostException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
    Message _message;
    while (_socket.isConnected()) {
        _message = (Message) _ois.readObject();
        System.out.print( _message.getAll());
        _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: The run method of ClientPeer should have a loop to receive more than one message from the server. - You should have seen one line in the client's console.

Comment: @laune I didn't see any line in the TextClient console ,but there's an infinite loop in the server console:it displays the message infinitely

Comment: Do you repeatedly create ClientPeer? Problem is probably elsewhere, not in the parts you've posted.

Comment: @laune yes.I am sorry but if I paste the full code I am afraid there will be 9 classes out here.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really unspecified. If you want to see it on the client console just initiate the console on the client-side and print out the messages. Can you tell more about the problem? Where you need help?

Comment: The problem is that the message does not appear on the TextClient console,and it should.